# Replacing string in all file types in Java

Tags: java, file, binary, str-replace

I want to replace String A into String B in all file types especially binary files. I tried with this:

```
byte[] fileContent= Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
String content= new String(fileContent,charset);
content=content.replace(A,B);
byte[] result= content.getBytes(charset);
Files.write(file.toPath(), result);
```

but it doesn't work with binary files such as JPG. With txt files it works good.

Then I wrote this:

```
            byte[] fileContent= Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());

            char[] charBuffer=new char[fileContent.length];

            for(int i=0;i<fileContent.length;i++)
            {
                charBuffer[i]=(char)fileContent[i];
            }

            String content=new String(charBuffer);
            content=content.replace(chainA, chainB);

            charBuffer=content.toCharArray();
            fileContent=new byte[charBuffer.length];

            for(int i=0;i<charBuffer.length;i++)
            {
                fileContent[i]=(byte)charBuffer[i];
            }
```

And it works great. And my question is: Is there any better way to replace two strings in binary and txt files?

And why my first code doesn't work with binary files?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
Charset isoCharset = Charset.forName ("ISO-8859-1");
byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes (file.toPath ());
String.content = new String (fileContent, isoCharset);
content = content.replace (chainA, chainB);
fileContent = content.getBytes (isoCharset);
```

Of course, it assumes that you know the right encoding ahead of creating the Charset object.

Comment: Works only on small files, large files will fill up your heap very quick.